# mac os Terminal name issue

Tags: java, macos, terminal, java-home

i'm new in macOs environment and after trying to set java home path a have now my terminal like that every time i launch it:

Last login: Wed Feb  1 22:03:04 on ttys001
export JAVA_HOME=$(/Users/myname/libexec/java_home)
myname@157 ~ %

please someone can help me to recover my terminal to his original state.

Comment: What did you change? Presumably there’s something in your ZSH configuration printing this.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Tim Moore i remember make modification in ".zshrc " so i used command:

> nano .zshrc

i delete what a did in this file.
and the probleme is gone